# Getting Error "Cannot perform a single-role upgrade using different versions of the SDK"

Tags: azure

This is my first post so please let me know if I post under wrong subject heading. 
I have upgraded my Azure SDK version from 2.4 to 2.7 and build the package for updating  Web role. During the update I am getting the error
  "Cannot perform a single-role upgrade using different versions of the SDK".

I have checked in all settings and versions of Azure reference  in my project and found all updated to 2.7. My understanding was Azure itself handles the roles SDK version based on the package.

I am not sure how to resolve this issue as I don't find any configuration  settings in Web role to upgrade SDK version.

Please let me know if anyone faced such issue in passed.  Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your deployment only has a single role you might try selecting `All` for the `Role` option instead of explicitly specifying the individual role when updating.